# How to calculate this basic Fourier Transform?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, definite-integrals

I am trying to calculate the Fourier Transform of $g(t)=e^{-\alpha|t|}$, where $\alpha > 0$.

Because there's an absolute value around $t$, that makes $g(t)$ an even function, correct? If that's the case, then I made the assumption that I can calculate FT integral from $0$ to $\infty$ and then multiply the result by $2$ to get the answer:

$G^*(f) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha t} e^{-j\omega t}dt = G(f) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(j\omega + \alpha)t}dt = \frac{e^{-(j\omega + \alpha)t}}{-(j\omega + \alpha)}\bigg|_0^\infty = 0 - \frac{1}{-(j\omega + \alpha)} = \frac{1}{j\omega + \alpha}$

$G(f) = 2G^*(f) = \frac{2}{j\omega + a}$

This is not the correct answer. If wolfram alpha is to be believed, then the answer should be:

$\frac{\alpha}{\omega^2 + \alpha^2}$

What did I do wrong? What are the correct steps to calculate this FT?

Comment: g(t) is even but its product with the complex exponential is not and that is what you are integrating. split the integral into two conjugate halves then add.

Comment: What wolfram alpha gives you is the *real* part of $\frac{1}{j\omega+\alpha}$. Multiply numerator and denumerator with $-j\omega + \alpha$ to see this...

Comment: @fgp Thanks, that helps explain a lot. Why do I have a $2$ in the numerator when wolfram alpha doesn't, though? And is the FT supposed to only have the real part of the solution?

Comment: @Nate No, but if you do as Paul told you to, i.e. compute the two halves separately (because, as he said, $e^{-j\omega t}$ *isn't* even!), you'll see that the second half yields the complex conjugate of the first half, i.e. the imaginary parts will cancel out. That'll still leave you with twice the value wolfram allegedly reports - dunno why that is - what did you enter into wolfram?

Comment: Hm, I tried computing `int[e^(-a|t|)e^(-iwt),t=-infinity..infinity]` with wolfram alpha, but it always just says "Computation time exceeded"...

Comment: @fgp This is the FT in wolfram alpha (I think the $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ is in there because they used a different definition for the FT): `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier+transform+exp%28-alpha*abs%28t%29%29`

Comment: @fgp Also, your and Paul's comments, and Matt L's answer, makes sense, but per my comment to Matt L's answer, it appears a condition has to be imposed on the solution, which doesn't seem right..

Comment: @Nate And how did that $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ suddenly get in?? I thought you said wolfram alpha claims the result is $\frac{\alpha}{\omega^2+\alpha^2}$ where as the integral *you* stated yieds $\frac{2\alpha}{\omega^2+\alpha^2}$. I have no doubt that the difference stems from different conventions as to how to normalization factor is split between forward and reverse transform, but you'll only get at the bottom of this if you're more carefull and more specific. As it stands, you're sending people on a bit of a wild goose chase...

Comment: @fgp I was just ignoring it because I knew (well, I was fairly certain) it was in there due to a different definition of the FT. I should have clarified that and been more specific, though. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha|t|}e^{-j\omega t}dt=\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{\alpha t}e^{-j\omega t}dt+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t}e^{-j\omega t}dt=\frac{1}{\alpha-j\omega}+\frac{1}{\alpha+j\omega}=\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}$$

Comment: For the second integral above, if you combine the exponentials you get $e^{(-j\omega+\alpha)t}$. So, in order for it to converge, do we have to impose the condition that $-j\omega+\alpha > 0$ ? Is there any way around imposing that condition? Wolfram Alpha doesn't have a condition like that in their solution.

Comment: No, $\alpha>0$ is sufficient for convergence because the magnitude of $e^{\pm j\omega t}$ always equals 1.

Comment: @Nate No, the only condition is $\alpha > 0$. $e^{j\omega t}$ is bounded - as can easily be seen by using that $e^{j\omega t} = \cos \omega t + j\sin \omega t$. (And BTW, since this is a math site, not an EE site, using $j$ in place of $i$ risks causing confusion. Not in this particular case - since this is supposed to be a fourier transform, the meaning is clear enough - but in general, be carefull...)

Comment: @fgp & Matt L. - Maybe I'm doing the intermediate step not shown here (the actual integration) wrong, then. What I'm getting is $\int_{-\infty}^0e^{\alpha t}e^{-j\omega t}dt=\int_{-\infty}^0e^{(\alpha-j\omega)t}dt=\frac{e^{(\alpha-j\omega)t}}{\alpha-j\omega}\bigg|_{-\infty}^{0}$. When evaluating that, if $\alpha -j\omega < 0$, then plugging in $-\infty$ for $t$ causes $(\alpha-j\omega)t > 0$ and you get $e^\infty$. Am I missing something?

Comment: $\alpha-j\omega<0$ does not make sense, it's a complex number! What you actually get is $e^{-j\omega t}e^{\alpha t}$ for $t\rightarrow -\infty$, and this term approaches 0, because the magnitude of $e^{-j\omega t}$ is 1.

Comment: @Nate You are very, very confused. $\alpha -j\omega$ *is not*, i repeat **is absolutely not** a real number. It's hence neither greater than nor less than zero, you simply *cannot* compare it to zero.

Comment: @fgp & Matt L. - Ohhhh.. I was really confused, but everything makes sense now! Thank you both so much for helping me to understand :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is even you have
$$
\hat g(\omega)=2\,\int_0^\infty g(t)\,\cos(j\,\omega\,t)\,dt,
$$
wich is the real part of
$$
2\,\int_0^\infty g(t)\,e^{j\,\omega\,t}\,dt.
$$